# How to install and use rails.vim in Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, ide, ubuntu, text-editor

I have google search and found nothing on it. DO anyone know any tutorial that is about installing and use rails.vim in ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also follow [this step-by-step recipe](https://github.com/JiriChara/vim-files).

Comment: This link does not have anything regarding rails.vim anymore.

Answer (score 3):

From [the website](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1567) for rails.vim.

> **install details** Extract the zip file
>   to ~/.vim (or vimfiles on Windows). 
>   To use the help, see :help
>   add-local-help.  In a nutshell,
>   :helptags ~/.vim/doc.

But I suggest you look into [pathogen](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2332) for managing your vim plugins. For directions on installing and usage check [this blog post](http://tammersaleh.com/posts/the-modern-vim-config-with-pathogen).